# Mvvmcross save ViewModelState

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm currently trying to navigate from a fragmentActivity to a activity and then back to the fragmentActivity I came from. I do this using:

```
await Mvx.Resolve<IMvxNavigationService>().Navigate<MainViewModel>();
```

The problem I run into when using this is that the ViewModels of all fragments inside of the fragmentActivity are recreated causing a error on this line(This line is inside of the constructor of all ViewModels of the fragments inside of fragmentActivity):

```
var viewModelService = Mvx.GetSingleton<IViewModelService>();
        viewModelService?.ViewModels.Add(ViewModelName, this);
```

This is because "ViewModelName" has already been added to viewModelService?.ViewModels. So my question is: Is there another way of navigating that does not recreate my Views and ViewModels?

Comment: Have you tried inbuilt navigation with ShowViewModel method?

Comment: IMvxNavigationService is the built in service in 5.x! ShowViewModel has been removed in the latest version. @saketkumar

Comment: ShowViewModel has not been removed yet, you can still use it.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Do you have a example on how can I use ShowViewModel to fix my problem?

Comment: I think you should log an issue on GitHub, there is clearly something wrong with the logic here. How you achieve what you are trying to do with ShowViewModel without anymore context I don't know.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I'll do that with IMvxNavigationService! Since that's what I'm using now. Or do you recommend ShowViewModel over IMvxNavigationService